# How to re add elementary OS PPAs?

Tags: release-juno

I have deleted all my elementary OS PPA due to some errors. I want to add those again. I have deleted update, security and all the PPAs of elementary OS.
PLEASE HELP ME!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the list of stock PPA that came with elementary OS 5.

Add these lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Add this to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list` file:

```
deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main
```

Add this to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list` file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic main
```

Add this to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list` file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic main
```