# Default source files needed

Tags: default, sources

Can anyone please send me default files of elementary OS

/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list

Comment: You can create these files yourself with any available text editor (as empty files), then open them and insert required lines into them: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/20771/17985

Answer (score 2):

Default content in elementary OS 5.1 HERA

## /etc/apt/sources.list

```
#deb cdrom:[elementary OS 5.0 _Juno_ - Stable amd64 (20181016)]/ bionic contrib main non-free

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

## /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list

```
deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main
```

## /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic main
```

## /etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic main
```