# Need List of Repositories for Updating Hera

Tags: repositories

I may have deleted some needed repositories. I need a list of the current repositories for updating elementary OS Hera.

Comment: Additionally, I need to have the repositories for Ubuntu LTS included. I do not have all repositories in my sources list activated. I simply need to know which repositories should be active.

Comment: Follow this tread:
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/20772/default-source-files-needed

Comment: Thanks, Ara. Your link provided the information that I needed.